# Extract data from Sybase ASE 15 using SSIS 2008 in Unicode format

Tags: ssis, oledb, sap-ase

I'm attempting to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) 2008 R2 to extract data from a Sybase ASE 15 database.

I've managed to configure the OLE DB Source with the correct connection information and can see the tables and data. However no matter what I try it always returns DT_STR columns.

I would like to have the data returned in Unicode format, without using the Derived Column / Data Conversion task, as the destination tables are all defined with NVARCHAR (DT_WSTR) column and it would be a bit of a pain to have to go through every column just to change the type.

Is there a way to define the connection string / set defaults on the login / other method to ensure that the OLE DB Data Source returns DT_WSTR columns instead of DT_STR when running a query?

Many thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the OLE DB Data source and select the **Advanced Editor**. Then go to the *Input and output Properties* tab.
Select the column that you're importing and change its dataType on the properties display on the right.

Alternatively you could have your OLE DB Source use a query to return its columns. Your SELECT statement can then `CAST()` your columns into the type you need.

I don't know why you dont want to use a derived column/data transformation transformation tho. It seems like it would be just the same amount if not more work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't want to use a derived columns / data conversion / editing the columns in the Advanced editor. I want to know if there is anything I can set in the connection details, server settings or SSIS code page so I don't have to mess around with this kind of setting and just work with DT_WSTR returned from the query.

Comment: I added another method, but i still dont see why you would want to do it like that. SSIS makes it extremely easy to manipulate data with its components. But oh well

Comment: I want the type set on the Ole db source so I don't have to manually mess around with other components for each string column. There are around 1000 columns!